# Incrementing and Decrementing a querystring parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string

In my current MVC project(the third question I've asked on this same project!), I have a 'Landing Page' which after one click of a button redirects to the following page URL:

*localhost:111111/AccountsFinance/Index?questionId=1*

I can edit the URL manually and change *Id=2* which does change what is displayed, but I need a button to do this of course.

Within this View, I have the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AccountsFinance", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //SOME CODE

    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Back" />
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Next" />
}
```

Here is my controller code, not sure if it is necessary for this question but better to include it than not to!

```
    public AccountsFinanceQuestion afqList = new AccountsFinanceQuestion();

    public ActionResult Index(string ans)
    {
        int qId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["questionId"]);

        using (S3WEntities1 ent = new S3WEntities1())
        {
            afqList.Question = ent.Questions.Where(w => w.QuQuestionId == qId).Select(s => s.QuQuestion).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            afqList.Answers = ent.Answers.Where(w => w.AnsQuestionId == qId).Select(s => s.AnsAnswer).ToList();
        }

        return View("Index", afqList);
    }
```

So how would I increment/decrement the *questionId=X* part of the query string so that it moves on to the next question/the previous question. This is all in the same view on the same method on the same controller. I also understand that this may not work so well for the very first question if the user clicks back, as the URL is completely different, but that is something to come on to at a later date.

Comment: Your question is not clear not me. Are you asking for `qID+1` in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to parse query string parameters manually - default binder will do it for you. Just define method parameter with corresponding name. E.g.

```
public ActionResult Index(int questionId)
```

Second, seems like you are reviewing details of some question. So I don't think that Index is appropriate action for that. I suggest to use Details or Edit:

```
public ActionResult Details(int questionId)
```

And regarding links to next and previous questions - you can just generate action links in your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Details", new { questionId = Model.QuQuestionId - 1 }
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Details", new { questionId = Model.QuQuestionId + 1 })
```

Also note, that your approach has several problems:

- What if some question was deleted and ids are not incremental anymore?
- What if current question has id = 1, i.e. it's a first question? It should not have link to previous question
- What if current questions is last one?

Easiest way to solve these problems - pass ids of previous and next questions to your view. You can use model properties for that, or you can use `ViewBag`:

```
ViewBag.PrevQuestionId = ent.Questions
    .Where(q => q.QuQuestionId < questionId)
    .OrderByDescending(q => q.QuQuestionId)
    .Select(q => q.QuQuestionId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then in View you can conditionally add link to previous question:

```
 @if (ViewBag.PrevQuestionId > 0) {
      @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Details", new { questionId = ViewBag.PrevQuestionId }
 }
```

Same with next question

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this in your controller:

```
int qId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["questionId"]);
Response.RedirectToRoute("current-route?questionId=" + qId++);
```

Comment: you shouldn't have to access or parse the querystring. The MVC action should simply accept an int.

Comment: Trust me, your doing it wrong if you using the underlying Request object. the whole point of the controller in the MVC pattern is to abstract the underlying base objects out of the equation. For example, how would you unit test the above?!

Comment: Also your Response redirect is wrong too. You want to return a result from the action, not (again) interact with the underlying objects. This is pretty much how things worked in 1999 with classic asp. Things have moved on now.

Comment: I', not talking about best practices.. I just want to help auther of question to make his code working :)

Comment: I'm not talking best practices, I'm talking fundamental basics of MVC. I'm sorry, but this answer is wrong (full stop)